# What is the big-O complexity of this code to count ways to make change?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

This algorithm computes the number of ways one can make change for n cents assuming one can use six types of coins. Singles, half dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies.

```
B(n)
count ← 0
s ← 0
while s ≤ n/100
   do srem ← n − 100*s
   s ← s + 1
   h ← 0
   while h ≤ srem/50
       do hrem ← srem − 50*h
       h ← h + 1
       q ← 0
       while q ≤ hrem/25
          do qrem ← hrem − 25*q
          q ← q + 1
          d ← 0
          while d ≤ qrem/10
             do drem ← qrem − 10*d
             d ← d + 1
             ni ← 0
             while ni ≤ drem/5
                 do ni ← ni + 1
                 count ← count + 1
return count
```

I have so far calculated: Time complexity `T(n) = 1 + a(1+b(1+c(1+d(1+e*1))))` a, b, c, d, e are the while loops.

In the worst case, s is n/100, so substituting that on a, and

```
srem <- n - 100*n/100 = 0,

T(n) = n/100(1 + 0) = Big-O(n).
```

But when s = 0,

```
T(n) = 1 + 0(1+ ....)
     = Big-O(1)
```

Is this how it is supposed to be done ? I couldn't find much examples related to while loops.